# How to have forge viewer to display elements with low level details?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

On revit, in 3D view, I have some plumbing pipes with low/medium level of details, so they are just shown as a wire:
[image: medium level of detail]
If I want to see them nicely, I move up level of detail and I see a nice pipe:
[image: high level of detail]

For some files, I cannot edit the original with Revit before sending to forge for conversion. I would like to know how can we see this pipe in forge viewer, even with low level of details?

For info, forge viewer has the element present in model hierarchy.

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand it correctly, you upload a "low details" Revit model (with plumbing pipes visualized as wires) to Forge, and in the Forge Viewer you would like to switch back to "full details"?

I'm afraid that is not possible. When converting the Revit model into a Forge Viewer format, all the original geometry is tessellated into triangle meshes, so there's no way to switch between levels of detail after that.

Answer (score 0):

I have been looking at this, and noticed that if i upload the revit model to forge the pipework comes out as singleline, fittings in high detail.

in a similar way to opening a revit file in navisworks directly without converting to a NWC first.

so you can get around it by uploading a NWC file to forge. This doesn't solve the issue, as id prefer to upload the revit file directly.